# Ayuda con problema en integración de Checkout Pro MercadoPago

Tags: php, javascript, mercadopago, mercadolibre, checkout

Tengo un problema con la integración de Checkout Pro de MercadoPago en un comercio eletrónico.

Pude generar los usuarios de prueba y todo como indica la documentación oficial (https://www.mercadopago.com.co/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/test-integration/). De hecho, el código que llevo implementado es prácticamente el mismo que indican en la documentación porque no he hecho la homologación.

Sin embargo, al darle clic al botón de pago NUNCA me muestra el formulario para pagar como USUARIO INVITADO, siempre me pide loguearme, es decir, se salta el paso de mostrar pasarelas de pago y formulario de usuario invitado y carga directo para loguearse en mercadopago.

El código que tengo implementado es:

```
require get_template_directory().'/vendor/autoload.php';
        // Agrega credenciales
        MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('TEST-55xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');


        // Crea un objeto de preferencia
        $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
        // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
        $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
        $item->title = 'Mi producto';
        $item->quantity = 1;
        $item->unit_price = 500;
        //$item->category_id = "home";
        $item->currency_id = "COP";
        $preference->items = array($item);

        $preference->back_urls = array(
            "success" => "https://www.tu-sitio/success",
            "failure" => "http://www.tu-sitio/failure",
            "pending" => "http://www.tu-sitio/pending"
        );

        $preference->save();

        ?>
        <form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
            <script
                    src="https://www.mercadopago.com.co/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
                    data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
            </script>
        </form>
```

[image: Lo que muestra al cargar el modal (NO DEBERÍA)]

[image: Lo que muestra al darle clic en cancelar (SE QUEDA ASÍ Y NUNCA CARGA NADA)]

[image: Lo que debería de mostrar al cargar el modal]

La primera imagen es lo que muestra al cargar el modal (NO DEBERÍA), la segunda lo que muestra al darle clic en cancelar (SE QUEDA ASÍ Y NUNCA CARGA NADA) y la última Lo que debería de mostrar al cargar el modal.

Quedo atento a su valiosa orientación, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Juan Jose, no se si ya lo resolviste. En caso de que no lo hayas hecho, podrias fijarte en la consola del browser si muestra algun error o en el http response, y si hay algo compartirlo acá?

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema, y habían dos razones.

- La url del checkout, tenía incorrecto el país. Si la cuenta es de colombia, la url debe finalizar ".co", argentina ".ar", etc.
- El monto de la compra era muy pequeño. Asegurarse de no poner precios que no sean válidos con la moneda que se realizará la compra. Por ejemplo, con 10 pesos Colombianos no me funcionaba, pero al cambiarlo por 1500 pesos Colombianos o más, funcionó.

Al corregir estos dos, me funcionó y se muestró la opción para usuario invitado.